# Why applescript doesn't accept file object in localized string command?

Tags: macos, localization, applescript, localizable.strings, applescript-objc

Following applescript throws error:

```
set thePath to path to application support from user domain as alias
set mystr to localized string "Add people to this note" in bundle file thePath
```

And the error is

```
error "Can’t make file (alias \"Macintosh HD:Users:shakes:Library:Application Support:\") into type file." number -1700 from file (alias "Macintosh HD:Users:shakes:Library:Application Support:") to file
```

What does this error means? `localized string` expects a `file` or `alias` object which `thePath` is then why this error?

FYI, [`localized string` reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW23) says:

```
Syntax
localized   string  text    required
from table   text   optional
in bundle   fileSpecifier   optional
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **folder** Application Support is not a **file**. Remove the `file` keyword.

```
set thePath to path to application support from user domain -- as alias is redundant
set mystr to localized string "Add people to this note" in bundle thePath
```

But the code is meaningless because the folder Application Support is not a bundle either.